# How to define additional or custom tags for default Spring Boot 2 metrics?

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, micrometer

Recently I switched to `Spring Boot 2` with `Micrometer`. As I got these shiny new metrics, I talked with our DevOps guys and we started exporting them to `Telegraf`.

To distinguish between different applications and application nodes, we decided to use tags. This works perfectly for custom metrics, but now I started thinking about the pre-defined. To achieve the same for default metrics, I need the ability to add extra tags for them as well.

Is it possible to achieve this? Am I doing this right?

**EDIT:** I tried next approach:

```
@Component
public class MyMetricsImpl implements MyMetrics {

    @Autowired
    protected MyProperties myProperties;
    @Autowired
    protected MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        this.meterRegistry.config()
                .commonTags(commonTags());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Tag> commonTags() {
        List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
        tags.add(Tag.of("application", myProperties.getApplicationName()));
        tags.add(Tag.of("node", myProperties.getNodeName()));
        return tags;
    }
}
```

The problem is that my metrics behave correctly and even some of the Boot's metrics (at least `http.server.requests`) see my tags. But `jvm.*`, `system.*`, `tomcat.*` and many others still don't have the needed tags.

Comment: Hi
Can you please tell me how you have written custom metrics for micrometer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are looking for common tags support, you can do it by registering a `MeterFilter` doing it.

See [this commit](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/commit/52e015a7f1507f167a290410b1d4e572f4e028c6) or [this branch](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/tree/common-tags) for an example.

With [the upcoming Spring Boot 2.1.0.M1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12933), you can use the following properties:

```
management.metrics.tags.*= # Common tags that are applied to every meter.
```

See [the reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-metrics-custom) for details.

UPDATED:

As the question has been updated, I checked the updated question with this `MeterFilter`-based approach and confirmed it's working as follows:

Request: `http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/jvm.gc.memory.allocated`

Response:

```
{
  "name" : "jvm.gc.memory.allocated",
  "measurements" : [ {
    "statistic" : "COUNT",
    "value" : 1.98180864E8
  } ],
  "availableTags" : [ {
    "tag" : "stack",
    "values" : [ "prod" ]
  }, {
    "tag" : "region",
    "values" : [ "us-east-1" ]
  } ]
}
```

I didn't check the approach which has been provided in the updated question but I'd just use the proven `MeterFilter`-based approach unless there's any reason to stick with the approach.

2nd UPDATED:

I looked into the approach and was able to reproduce it with [this branch](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/tree/so-51552889).

It's too late to apply common tags in `@PostConstruct` as some metrics have been registered already. The reason why `http.server.requests` works is that it will be registered with the first request. Try to put a breakpoint on [the point of filters' application](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/MeterRegistry.java#L525) if you're interested in it.

In short, try the above approach which is similar to the upcoming Spring Boot out-of-box support.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed response! I appreciate that you took your time and checked this. I'll check your suggestion in my project and will accept your answer or get back to you here. You're awesome!

Comment: how to fix this: "value" : 1.98180864E8 ?

Answer (score 8):

**For Server:**
(i.e. `@RestController`)
To add custom metrics tags for reactive-spring-boot application, in addition to default tags provided by the spring-boot framework.

Provide one or more `@Beans` that implement `WebFluxTagsContributor`
OR
To replace the default tags, provide a `@Bean` that `implements WebFluxTagsProvider`.
[Reference implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61679022/2987755) which uses `Spring-WebMVC` as one of the answers.
[Ref:](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics.supported.spring-webflux)

Following implementation is in groovy.

```
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Tag
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.WebFluxTagsContributor
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange

@Component
class CustomWebClientExchangeTagsProvider implements WebFluxTagsContributor {

    final KEY = "key"

    /**
     * Provides tags to be associated with metrics for the given {@code exchange}.
     * @param exchange the exchange
     * @param ex the current exception (maybe {@code null})
     * @return tags to associate with metrics for the request and response exchange
     */
    @Override
    Iterable<Tag> httpRequestTags(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable ex) {
        String apiKey = exchange.request.queryParams[KEY] ?: "default_api_key"
        HttpStatus status = exchange.response.statusCode ?: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
        HttpMethod method = exchange.request.method ?: HttpMethod.OPTIONS
        String group = (status.value() >= 500 ? "5XX" : (status.value() >= 400) ? "4XX" : (status.value() >= 300) ? "3XX" : "NONE")

        Tag statusTag = Tag.of("status", status.value().toString())
        Tag methodTag = Tag.of("method", method.toString())
        Tag apiKeyTag = Tag.of(KEY, apiKey)
        Tag groupTag = Tag.of("group", group)

        return Arrays.asList(statusTag, methodTag, apiKeyTag, groupTag)
    }
}
```

**Metrics tags:**

- Verify for client: metric `http.client.requests.percentile` or `http.client.requests`.

```bash
http://localhost:8010/metrics/http.client.requests
```

- Verify for server:

```bash
http://localhost:8010/metrics/http.server.requests
```

similarly, tags will be added for `http.server.requests.percentile` metrics

```json
{
    "name": "http.server.requests",
    "description": null,
    "base_unit": "milliseconds",
    "measurements": [
        {
            "statistic": "COUNT",
            "value": 17.0
        },
        {
            "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
            "value": 8832.186054
        },
        {
            "statistic": "MAX",
            "value": 6.514132
        }
    ],
    "available_tags": [
        {
            "tag": "exception",
            "values": [
                "None",
                "ResponseStatusException"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "method",
            "values": [
                "GET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "application",
            "values": [
                "myapplication"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "uri",
            "values": [
                "/myapplication/v1/abcd",
                "/manage/metrics/{requiredMetricName}",
                "/manage",
                "/manage/metrics",
                "/myapplication/v1/windows",
                "/**"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "outcome",
            "values": [
                "CLIENT_ERROR",
                "SERVER_ERROR",
                "SUCCESS"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "key",
            "values": [
                "default_api_key",
                "[abcd]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "status",
            "values": [
                "404",
                "200",
                "502"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "group",
            "values": [
                "4XX",
                "NONE",
                "5XX"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

OR

If you are using `prometheus`
you can verify custom tags as follows

```bash
http://localhost:8010/prometheus
```

**Client:**

```
http_client_requests_seconds_count{application="myapplication",clientName="myhostname.com",method="POST",outcome="CLIENT_ERROR",status="403",uri="/urlIamTryingToHit/v1/list",} 1.0
```

Client has only default tags provided by spring-boot and no custom tags.

**Server:**

```
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{application="myapplication",exception="None",group="4XX",key="default_api_key",method="GET",outcome="CLIENT_ERROR",status="404",uri="/manage/metrics/{requiredMetricName}",} 0.004154207
```

We can observe `group="4XX"`, `key="default_api_key"`, `method="GET"`, `status="404"` along with existing default tags.

---

**For Client:**
To customise the tags, and depending on your choice of client, you can provide a `@Bean` that `implements RestTemplateExchangeTagsProvider` or  `WebClientExchangeTagsProvider`.
There are convenience static functions in `RestTemplateExchangeTags` and `WebClientExchangeTags`.
[Ref:](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics.supported.http-clients)

Answer (score 2):

In response to comment under my original question, here is a small example of adding custom metrics:

```java
package io.github.stepio.examples.metrics;

import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Tag;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

@Component
public class MyImportantComponent {

    protected static final String CONNECTIONS_CURRENT = "connections.created";
    protected static final String CONNECTIONS_IDLE = "connections.idle";
    protected static final String CONNECTIONS_MAX = "connections.max";

    protected static final String PREFIX_REQUESTS_FOR_SERVICE = "requests";

    protected static final String SERVICE = "service";

    protected AtomicInteger connectionMax = new AtomicInteger();

    @Autowired
    protected MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    @Override
    public List<Tag> tags() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void trackConnectorsCurrent(AtomicInteger counter) {
        this.meterRegistry.gauge(CONNECTIONS_CURRENT, tags(), counter);
    }

    @Override
    public void trackConnectorsIdle(Collection<?> collection) {
        this.meterRegistry.gaugeCollectionSize(CONNECTIONS_IDLE, tags(), collection);
    }

    @Override
    public void submitConnectorsMax(final int value) {
        this.meterRegistry.gauge(CONNECTIONS_MAX, tags(), this.connectionMax).set(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void incrementRequestsForService(String serviceName) {
        this.meterRegistry.counter(PREFIX_REQUESTS_FOR_SERVICE, tags(SERVICE, serviceName)).increment();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `spring-boot-actuator` and you need to add dynamical tags to default metrics
simply define a `WebMvcTagsProvider` bean:

```java
/**
 * Default implementation of WebMvcTagsProvider.<br>
 * @author Jon Schneider<br>
 * @since 2.0.0
 */
public class DefaultWebMvcTagsProvider implements WebMvcTagsProvider {

    @Override
    public Iterable<Tag> getTags(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            Throwable exception) {
        return Tags.of(WebMvcTags.method(request), WebMvcTags.uri(request, response), WebMvcTags.exception(exception),
                WebMvcTags.status(response), WebMvcTags.outcome(response));
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Tag> getLongRequestTags(HttpServletRequest request, Object handler) {
        return Tags.of(WebMvcTags.method(request), WebMvcTags.uri(request, null));
    }

}
```