# How to create a multi-value tag metric gauge?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-micrometer

Already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552889/is-it-possible-to-define-additional-tags-for-default-spring-boot-2-metrics) but with no lucky.

All examples I've found just show how to create a single value tag like this:

```
{
  "name" : "jvm.gc.memory.allocated",
  "measurements" : [ {
    "statistic" : "COUNT",
    "value" : 1.98180864E8
  } ],
  "availableTags" : [ {
    "tag" : "stack",
    "values" : [ "prod" ]
  }, {
    "tag" : "region",
    "values" : [ "us-east-1" ]
  } ]
}
```

But I need to create a multi value tag like this:

```
availableTags: [
{
    tag: "method",
    values: [
        "POST",
        "GET"
    ]
},
```

My code so far:

```
    List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
    tags.add( Tag.of("test", "John") );
    tags.add( Tag.of("test", "Doo") );
    tags.add( Tag.of("test", "Foo Bar") );
    Metrics.gauge("my.metric", tags, new AtomicLong(3) );
```

As you can see I think I can just repeat the key but this is not the case and the second parameter of `Tag.of` is a String and not a String Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this was the real intent of authors of these metering libraries - to provide a multi-value tag for a metric.

The whole point of metrics tags is to provide a "discriminator" - something that can be used later to retrieve metrics whose tag has a specific, single, value.

Usually, this value is used in metrics storage systems, like Prometheus, DataDog, InfluxDB and so on. And above this Grafana can incorporate a single tag value in its queries.

The only possible use case of such a request that I see is that it will be possible to see the metrics value in an actuator in a kind of more convenient way, but again it's not the main point of the whole capability here, so,  bottom line I doubt that its possible at all.

Comment: Uh. Ok... but what is the point of `values` be an array instead a String like `tag` if they think no more values will be added? I mean if second parameter of `Tag.of( K, V )` is a String why it is represented by an Array in the metric endpoint? And why it is called `values` instead just `value` ?

Comment: I think its a format of serialization for a concrete metrics storage system, I'm not really into details at such a deep level... I know that micrometer adjusts itself (by exposing a per-system registry) to the format...

Comment: I basically provided an answer from a purely practical perspective (read, we use this stack in production system :) ). Could you please explain about the actual usage of this feature? Of course you can extend micrometer to support this is the concrete metrics system indeed permits this, but for what? Will you be able to build a grafana dashboard bases on this information for example?

Comment: I need to track all logged users in my Grafana dashboard. What I need is a metric to show the users count in its main value and a tag called `users` with all users names inside the `values`... just like the `http.server.requests` metric do in its `uri` tag.

Comment: I think this answer and the answer on the issue you raised gave enough explanation but I just wanted to point out that for Spring Boot Actuator's metrics endpoint, "values" in "availableTags" shows collection of distinct tag values from distinct metrics. For example, the "method" tag you mentioned has two tag values, "POST" and "GET" and they are distinct tag values from distinct metrics which are one having "POST" value for the tag and another having "GET" value.

Comment: Our team also needs this functionality.  Use case described in micrometer GH issue (too long for SO comment): https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/1432#issuecomment-1514728310