# Dynamic Tags to Spring metrics

Tags: spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

Is it possible to add dynamic tags to default spring metrics using micrometer?

I am trying to add a custom tag to http default metrics that spring provides.
I got this answer which explains how to add common tags [How to define additional or custom tags for default Spring Boot 2 metrics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552889/how-to-define-additional-or-custom-tags-for-default-spring-boot-2-metrics)
but what i want to know is if i can add the new tag dynamically instead of hardcoding the value as in the other answer?

Answer (score 1):

From Spring Boot 3.0.0 `WebMvcTagsContributor` is deprecated and the recommended way is to extend `DefaultServerRequestObservationConvention` - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics.supported.spring-mvc

To add a custom tag that can take values from the request context:

```
@Override
public KeyValues getLowCardinalityKeyValues(ServerRequestObservationContext context) {
  return super.getLowCardinalityKeyValues(context).and("tagKey", "tagValue");
}
```

Choose the high or low cardinality method based on your tag needs.

Answer (score 0):

See the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.8/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics.supported.spring-mvc

> To add to the default tags, provide one or more `@Beans` that implement `WebMvcTagsContributor`. To replace the default tags, provide a `@Bean` that implements `WebMvcTagsProvider`.

and

> To add to the default tags, provide one or more beans that implement `WebFluxTagsContributor`. To replace the default tags, provide a bean that implements `WebFluxTagsProvider`.